# Can't mount usb drives in Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, mount, alpine-linux

When I try to mount /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdb2 (which is my usb drive), I get this error:

```
doas mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usbdrive
mount: mounting /dev/sdb2 on /mnt/usbdrive failed: Invalid argument
```

I've tried to use different mount points like /run/media and /media, but it gives the same error. Help would be appreciated

Comment: What's in your `/etc/doas.conf`? What does `sudo dmesg | grep mount` show?

Comment: Try specifying the type of filesystem.

Comment: Just had this same issue and before I had a chance to validate which version I was using, I had a suspicion that the busybox mount was the culprit and ran `apk add mount`. Then it worked.